# Creating custom NSUserNotificationCenter instance

Tags: objective-c, nsusernotificationcenter

How can I create a new, custom `NSUserNotificationCenter` instance? I don't mean `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]`, I mean something like `[NSUserNotificationCenter new]` (which doesn't work, for me).

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: 1. is there any reason why you want your own `NSUserNotificationCenter`? Why doesn't the default one work for you? 2. *doesn't work* is not very indicative. What do you mean?

Comment: When I say that [NSUserNotificationCenter new] doesn't work I mean that making it deliver notifications doesn't show any notification on the screen. The default one DOES work for me, but for some reason (which is not relevant) I'd like to know how to create another center.

Comment: You can't and there's probably nothing that can be done about that. Why do you want to do this? Maybe we can help with the real problem.

Comment: I don't have a real problem, I'm just making experiments   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do this BECAUSE the class that is the real NotificationCenter is **NOT** the class `NSUserNotificationCenter`. :)

The user notification center that does the **real work is the private class** `_NSConcreteUserNotificationCenter`

which is what you get back by default.
`[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]` => `gets t_NSConcreteUserNotificationCenter`

the `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]` is a factory method and not just a short way to do alloc/init